# How is "dietary cholesterol" processed in a human body?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, biochemistry

Person eats an egg that is high in animal cholesterol ("dietary cholesterol").
What do chemical reactions play a role in breaking down it in stomach?

Comment: It isn't broken down.

Comment: Why? Any references?

Comment: I'm not getting your question, it's simply absorbed in intestines. Maybe you ask how it's separated from proteins? Or metabolised?

Comment: OK. It's absorbed in intenstines. Does it enter blood stream after absorbtion or metabolism?  I have basic knowledge in this topic, and want to learn more. I googled it and the search results are not explaining the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most lipids, such as **cholesterol** (and triglycerides), are nonpolar and therefore very hydrophobic molecules. In order to be transported in watery blood, such molecules first must be made more water-soluble by combining them with proteins produced by the liver and intestine.

Lipids and proteins associate noncovalently to form **lipoproteins** (globular micelle like particles that consist of a nonpolar core of triacylglycerols and cholesteryl esters surrounded by an amphiphilic coating of protein, phospholipid, and cholesterol):

[image]

Lipoproteins have been classified into five broad categories on the basis of their functional and physical properties:

- **1**. Chylomicrons, which transport exogenous (dietary) triacylglycerols and cholesterol from the intestines to the tissues.

*Chylomicrons therefore function to deliver **dietary cholesterol** and triacylglycerols to muscle and adipose tissue and dietary cholesterol to the liver.*

- **2–4**. Very low density lipoproteins (VLDL), intermediate density lipoproteins (IDL), and low density lipoproteins (LDL), a group of related particles that transport endogenous triacylglycerols and cholesterol from the liver to the tissues (the liver synthesizes triacylglycerols from excess carbohydrates).
- **5**. High density lipoproteins (HDL), which transport endogenous cholesterol from the tissues to the liver.

Circulating HDL acquires its cholesterol by extracting it from cell-surface membranes and converts it to cholesteryl esters through the action of *lecithin-cholesterol acyltransferase (LCAT)*, an enzyme that is activated by apoA-I. HDL therefore functions as a cholesterol scavenger.

[image]

*This enzyme transfers a fatty acid residue from atom C2 of lecithin to cholesterol with the concomitant formation of lysolecithin*

The cholesteryl esters are hydrolyzed by a lysosomal lipase to yield cholesterol, which is subsequently incorporated into the cell membranes. Any excess intracellular cholesterol is reesterified for storage within the cell through the action of *acyl- CoA:cholesterol acyltransferase (ACAT).*

References

- Principles of Anatomy and Physiology 13e Tortora, Derrickson
- Biochemistry Voet and Voet: Lipoproteins

Comment: Based on the answer, I understand now that dietary and liver-generated cholosterol both are carried by blood to build the cell membranes around human body.